# Need help updating mongodb using a updateMany mongoose route within a .save() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with the "PhoneNumberDb.updateMany"

Everything else works but for some reason when I get to the part where I am updating the PhoneNumberDb with an array of IDs, my mongo database is not updating. The "newSMSGroupPhoneNumberReRoute" is an array of ids like ['h877hn8h87hnnYubtj','78gngy8gn7ggGGHvy']

The reason I am writing this as so is so that when I create a new group, I want to be able to select numbers I can have in this group. But in order to update that group, I am using the .save() function to grab the group ID as soon as it is created, then I am updating that group with the array of number IDs.

Am I doing this incorrectly?

This is one of my routes:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const PhoneNumberDb = mongoose.model('phone_number')
const smsGroupDb = mongoose.model('sms_group')

module.exports = app => {

    // Create SMS Group
    app.post('/api/smsgroups', async (req, res) => {
        const { group_name, group_description, members, newSMSGroupPhoneNumberReRoute } = req.body

        const sms_group = new smsGroupDb({
            status: "Active",
            group_name,
            group_description,
            members,
            _user: req.user.id
        })

        await sms_group.save((err, group) => {
            PhoneNumberDb.updateMany(
                {_id: newSMSGroupPhoneNumberReRoute },
                { _sms_group: group._id },
                {new: true})
        })

        res.send(sms_group)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is was. I needed to make it an async function:

```
        await sms_group.save(async (err, group) => {
            await PhoneNumberDb.updateMany(
                { _id: { $in: newSMSGroupPhoneNumberReRoute } },
                { $set: { _sms_group : group._id } },
                {new: true})
        })
```